# Pi not recognising 2.5" HDD over powered USB Hub

Tags: hard-drive, usb-power, usb-hub

So after finally setting up OpenElec I decided to also get a powered USB hub.
Got [this one](http://www.belkin.com/us/F4U020-Belkin/p/P-F4U020/) for cheap from work. The power supply for the HUB outputs read: +5V ⎓1A

I connected a 2.5" HDD in a USB 2.0 enclosure to the hub and then the hub to the pi, but it doesn't recognise it and I can hear the HDD ticking in an odd way.

Any ideas why this doesn't work? I connected something that measures current over USB and it reads 5V on both my MacBook's USB port directly and the USB Hub.
When the HDD is connected to my MacBook it reads 5V/0.31A and when connected to the HUB: 5V/0.21A

Is this because of the difference in Ampere that the drive doesn't work? Using an Apple USB Charger for the Pi itself.

Comment: unlikely, does the drive work with another computer?

Comment: Ticking means there is not even power (or head crash) - Plug into a normal machine and see if it spins up and shows up. Its possible the HDD you are trying to use, is one of those not compatible for USB powering up.

Comment: @SteveRobillard yep it works perfectly on my MacBook, powered from the USB port.

Comment: @ppumkin I've been using it powered from my usb port on both my MacBook and other MacBooks.

Comment: I dont think this is a Pi related problem ...

Comment: most of the time the issue is an unstable power supply - my guess would be that the 5V 1A doesn't really deliver what it should. I'm using an usb hub with external power supply which supports 4A and I had never any problems with external drives.